# FirebaseMessaging module not found

Tags: objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When ever I write @import FirebaseMessaging; is says -

Module 'FirebaseMessaging' not found

What I did - I install the pods with only Firebase/Core, but after that I realised Firebase/Messaging is also necessary to enable push notifications.

[image: Sample Image]

Then I wrote pod 'Firebase/Messaging' in the pod file and install the pods again.

The pod folder contains the folder as Firebase Messaging, but when I import it it says no module found.

Comment: Try closing and reopening your workspace, sometimes this is the only solution, when everything is alright.

Comment: Done everything. Even deleted the workspace and made a new one. @BhavinKansagara

Answer (score 5):

You dont need to import `FirebaseMessaging`

Just add `@import Firebase` and you will get access to FIRMessaging

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and I could solve it this way:

if you have a framework that has `Firebase/Messaging` as it's dependency, and if you have set your framework's build settings to:

```
Build Active Architecture only
    Debug    No
    Release  No
```

you will get `FirebaseMessaging module not found error`. just try to make it like this:

```
Build Active Architecture only
    Debug    Yes
    Release  No
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Turns out that you need to place

```
use_frameworks!
```

in your Podfile. My Podfile now looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.4'
use_frameworks!
target 'YourTarget' do

pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Bolts'

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
# any other Firebase modules you need
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import FirebaseMessaging separately in the latest Firebase SDK according to the latest https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client:

`@import Firebase` &  just include in your pod file

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If anything is not working, then you should try

1. Comment the **Firebase** and **FirebaseMessaging** from your Podfile
2. run **pod install**
3. add following to your pod file

   ```
   pod 'Firebase', '~> 5.4'
   pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 3.0'
   ```
4. next is to **pod install --repo-update**
5. close your project and open workspace.
6. when you import the **Firebase** and try to import **FirebaseMessaging**, it will show you red marked lines, which means once you import **Firebase** it already imported the red marked modules in it.

[image: this]

Try it, if it fixes. I have tried and everything is working fine.

Comment: this is not the best solution but it actually work

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these process :

1. Clean the Application from product > clean
2. Close the Application
3. Again Open workspace of the Application
4. Again clean.

Hope it will help to you.Thank you.

Comment: Done everything. Even deleted the workspace and made a new one. Application has been closed and cleaned a lot of times but error still exist